# Angular Instant Search - Update HTML config based on URL params

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

I'm currently using Angular with Angular Instant Search.

**1 - Dynamically update the HTML config based on URL param change**

- I have a split screen application. Folders on the left. Projects on
  the right.
- When clicking on a folder, the folder ID in the URL is modified
- My projects component subscribes to these changes and updates a local varaible for my folder ID
- I use this folder ID in my Angular Instant Search config.

**Reading the change of folder id in the url**

```
    setUrlParams(){
       this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((urlParameters) => {    
          this.folder_id = urlParameters['folderId'];
          this.setSearchConfig( this.folder_id);    
        });
    }
```

**Updating my Angular Instant Search config**

```
  setSearchConfig(folder_id){

    this.configOption = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      appId: "appID",
      indexName: "projects",
      routing: false,
      searchParameters: {
        facetsRefinements: {
          project_folder: [folder_id]
        }
      },
    };

  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="configOption">

   <ais-search-box placeholder='Search for products'></ais-search-box>

   <ais-hits>
      <ng-template let-hits="hits">
         <div *ngFor="let hit of hits">
           Hit {{hit.objectID}}: {{hit.project_title}}
         </div>
       </ng-template>
    </ais-hits>

</ais-instantsearch>
```

On the initial load, this works great. However, when clicking on a folder and updating the ID, the correct ID is passed into the "setSearchConfig" function. But the HTML isn't updating unless I refresh the page.

**Question**
How do I make the HTML dynamically update?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
// 1. Create a search param object

searchParameters = {}



// 2. Call a function (setSearchParams) on url change

setUrlParams(){
   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((urlParameters) => {    
      this.folder_id = urlParameters['folderId'];
      this.setSearchConfig( this.folder_id);    
   });
}


// 3. Set the search param filters to the new folder id

setInstantSearchParams(folder_id){
   this.searchParameters = {
      filters: "project_folder: '" + folder_id + "'"
   }
}
```

Add the following to the HTML

```
<ais-configure [searchParameters]="searchParameters"></ais-configure>
```